# How to make a filter in Django Listview queryset

Tags: django

I have a list of brands. Each brand has a list of categories
I want to make each brand a link. And when the user click the brand he passes to the page with all the categories related to that brand

Here is a template with brands:

```
<ul>
    {% for brand in object_list %}
        <li><a href="{{ brand.get_absolute_url pk }}">{{ brand.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And here is the view:

```
class CategoryListView(ListView):
    model = Category
    queryset = Category.objects.filter(brand=pk)
    template_name = 'category_list.html'
```

But it gives an error. Can someone help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) method:

```
class CategoryListView(ListView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'category_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
       qs = super().get_queryset(**kwargs)
       return qs.filter(brand_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

And the url should look like this:

```
path('category/<int:pk>/', CategoryListView.as_view())
```